# Is it faster to cache the size of std::vector

Tags: c++, caching, optimization, hoisting

I'm looking at a C++ class that wraps around std::vector and stores the size of the vector. The class updates this size everytime the vector is modified leading to a lot of redundant code (as an up-to-date size is always available from the size() method).  Is this truly faster or would the compiler optimize iterated usage of size() anyway?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to say!

Comment: Can you give an example of an iterated usage? Why isn't the vector method (probably inlined and already doing the bookkeeping) good enough?

Comment: Perhaps the class originally used an array and had to keep track of the size. Then somebody replaced the array with a vector but did not care enough to remove the size logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector::size` has constant time complexity, so yes, it is already stored in the vector and the code is redundant.

Comment: Is that assured somewhere in the standard?

Comment: Constant time complexity could also mean that there's a "sleep(1000)" in the implementation of size(). Constant time does not mean that the function returns quickly, which is what you're interested in when wondering whether to cache the return value.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: `std::vector::size()` doesn't sleep. It is awake all the time.

Comment: @Nawaz: Probably not, my point is that the defined runtime complexity of some function is not a good argument in deciding whether to cache the return value or not. Looking at the output of a profiler or a disassembler would be a good argument.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: The answer also says, *"it is **already stored** in the vector and the code is redundant"*, or it computes the difference between `_End` and `_Begin`; neither makes much difference!

Comment: @nawaz the vc++ implementation computes `size()` as a pointer difference, still `O(1)` but not quite the same as returning a cached size variable

Comment: Actually, if you look at libstdc++, *it is not stored*. The implementation is: `T* _M_begin; T* _M_end; T* _M_capacity`. Of course, since the size is just `_M_end - _M_begin`, it's trivial to derive it from what is stored.

Comment: @rhalbersma: That still *stores*, not size itself, but the pointers. `return _Size;` and `return _End - _Begin` make no difference.

Comment: @Nawaz In g++ and MS, the size is _not_ stored in the vector, as such.  A pointer to the end of the active data is stored, however, so calculating the size is only a simple pointer subtraction.  It's hard to imagine a situation where the time gained by caching would outweigh the time necessary to manage the cached value, however.

Comment: @nawaz it might make a difference if you count clock cycles for size() even if it saves time for the typical user of vector

Comment: @Nawaz It could.  Don't forget that pointer subtraction requires a division by a constant.  Which on some machines can be rather slow, especially if the constant isn't a power of 2.  (I still don't think that there would be any real scenarios where systematically caching can be a gain.  But there could be cases where caching it locally would be, e.g. `for (int i = 0, end = v.size(); i != end; ++ i)`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze The compiler will take care of that kind of micro optimization for you. A division by a non-pow 2 constant is also translated to a multiplication.

Comment: Great. Thanks for reassuring this intuition.

Comment: @rasmus ah so the suffiently smart and optimizing compiler really does exist? ;-)

Comment: @rasmus A division is a multiplication?  I don't think so.  The compilers I know will convert division by a constant into a combination of shifts and adds or subtracts, but it can still add up to a number of cycles.  Generally not significant, of course.

Comment: @JamesKanze No, any constant division can be converted to a constant multiplication modulus 2^n. See for example [Granlund](http://81.200.6.209/lib/pdf/Granlund%20T.Division%20by%20invariant%20integers%20using%20multiplication.pdf). Try to compile x/3, where x is unsigned using gcc -O3 and look at the assembly.

Comment: @rasmus Interesting.  I wasn't aware of this.  I know that compilers can (and do) convert division by a constant into a combination of shifts and adds or subtracts, but I wasn't aware of the conversion to multiplication.

Answer (score 11):

First, unlike what is stated in the previous postings, the
implementations of `std::vector` that I've seen (MS and g++) do
*not* cache the size.  On the other hand, it can be calculated
by a simple pointer subtraction, and anything you do to cache
the size will almost certainly add more overhead than it saves.

Comment: I think this (as all the other answers) is correct in that caching the return value probably hurts more than it helps, but this one should be the accepted answer because it gives the correct reason *why* caching would not be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

On all implementations I've seen, caching would be *slower*. It's just wasting memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the standard library implementation of `vector::size` is just returning a cached size, not recalculating it each time.